# Building an interval-based grid

Tags: javascript, performance, array

I have an interesting problem to solve and despite having a running solution, I was wondering where I could improve it.

In a range from 1 to 1000, I want to create an array with different increments according to the current interval.
So, from 1.0 to 2.0, the increment should be 0.01, from 2.0 to 4.0 it should be 0.02, and so on. There are many intervals. The final result yields an array with 350 fields.

I've come up with a super basic, easy to implement solution using ifs. So it goes something like:

```
// In one file I have:
const grid = new Grid().buildGrid();
console.log(grid); // And expect a grid which respects the rules defined in the below class.

// Grid Class:
class Grid {
    constructor() {
        this.array = [];
    }

buildGrid() {
    _createKeysWithTicks(this.array);
}

_createKeysWithTicks(array){
    let i = 1.0;
    while (i < 1000){
        i = parseFloat((i + findStepSize(i)).toFixed(2));
            array.push(i);
    }
    return array;
}

findStepSize(number) {
    let res;
    if (number >= 1.0 && number < 2.0) {
        res = 0.01;
    } else if (number >= 2.0 && number < 4.0) {
        res = 0.02;
    } else if (number >= 4.0 && number < 5.0) {
        res = 0.1;
    } else if (number >= 5.0 && number < 10.0) {
        res = 0.5;
    } else if (number >= 10.0 && number < 50.0) {
        res = 1.0;
    } else if (number >= 50.0 && number < 100.0) {
        res = 10;
    }

    return res;
}
```

However, this is not elegant, at all because I get numerous if statements. I could swap for a switch statement, thus reducing the number of comparisons, which is nice. But does it improve performance?

The suggestion is:

```
findStepSize(i) {
    let res;
    switch (number):
        case(number >= 1.0 && number < 2.0) {
            res = 0.01;
            break;
        case(number >= 2.0 && number < 4.0) {
            res = 0.02;
            break;
        case(number >= 4.0 && number < 5.0) {
            res = 0.1;
            break;
        case(number >= 5.0 && number < 10.0) {
            res = 0.5;
            break;
        case(number >= 10.0 && number < 50.0) {
            res = 1.0;
            break;
        case(number >= 50.0 && number < 100.0) {
            res = 10;
            break;
    }
    return res;
}
```

The increments are not linear, otherwise the solution could be different.

How would you optimize or clean this code?

*Note:* I understand and respect the rules of this community and I appreciate your feedback. Unfortunately, I cannot disclose much more details. If this is still not sufficient for you to think of how would you get rid of those If statements, I can't help much more because I can't simply provide more details. In fact, the data above is random and it's not the use case.

Comment: Is the real purpose of this for labelling the axes of a plot or chart?  If that's the case, it might make a better basis for the question title, to give a high-level overview of the objective.

Comment: No, it's not. The goal is built a sports betting grid so I can use those values in another place. However, those are business rules and seems a good option to have this part independent of the rest of the code so that if the rules change we only need to modify one single file/class.

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea for it to be independent of the rest of the code - I'm just looking for a better title to set the context for reviewers.  At the moment, I'm still struggling to understand what the requirements are, and why they are like that.

Comment: Hum, apologies for it not being too clear. I also do not want to reveal too many details regarding the problem because I'm not sure how much I can share. 

The context is that this array will be used to search these generated values in other data sources. Lets say you need these inputs to get all values that have a key 1.01, 1.02, ... and so on.

Comment: Please put actually functional code that reviewers can run... not snippets from inside a class.

Comment: If you think it is that required, I can make up something that would still apply to my question. I just can't share the real case.  Regardless, my question is about avoiding many if statements when the conditions are dynamic or which control flow option I should use instead of several if statements

Comment: Furthermore, the code snippet provided is in JavaScript but I feel the eventual answer will still apply in other languages

Comment: You can make an array with the ranges and the increment and then iterate array and find matching corresponding index and return increment

Comment: your definition for `findStepSize` uses local variable `i` but it's never used in the function. Do you mean `number`?

Comment: @GustavoSilva So, you are creating an array of Floats? And the array is: 1.01, 1.02, 1.03, ... 1.98, 1.99, 2.00, 2.02, 2.04, 2.06, ... 3.96, 3.98, 4.00, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, ... 4.8, 4.9, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, ... 9.5, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, ... 980.0, 990.0, 1000.0? Is that correct? So, 355 items in your array? (1.01-2.0 is 100 items. 2.02-4.0: 100 items. 4.1-5.0: 10 items. 5.5-10.0: 10 items. 11.0-50.0: 40 items. 60.0-1000.0: 95 items. 100+100+10+10+40+95: 355 items. Is that correct?

Comment: For this example, that's correct, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that you're iterating in increasing order, i.e. the trivial fact that if a number is greater than `n`, then it's also greater than any number below `n`; thus you can just keep track of the latest threshold you passed and only check if you've reached the next one.

```
let thresholds = [2, 4, 5, 10, 50, 100, 1000];
let increments = [0.01, 0.02, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 10];
let p = 0;

function createKeysWithTicks(array) {
    let i = 1.0;
    while (i < 1000) {
        array.push(Number(i.toFixed(2)));
        i += increments[p];
        if (i >= thresholds[p]) {
            p++;
        }
    }
 }
```